# How to extract only third-level domains from the string using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, and I'm currently trying to work with regular expressions. I need to extract only the valid third-level domains. The problem is that along with valid domains, I get part of the fourth -level domain as a third-level domain. But I don 't want to extract the fourth-level domain even partially.

How can i solve this problem and where is the error in my regular expression?

**My RegEx:**

```
(?<=[^\.])\b([A-Za-z]+\://)?((?<=[^\w+\-\-])[A-Za-z0-9]+)(\-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)(\-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?(\.[A-Za-z]+)(/\w+\.\w+)?
```

**regex101's page:**

https://regex101.com/r/uO5lJ0/15

Thanks for your help, guys!

**UPD:** I don't want to use modules like tldextract to solve this problem. Sorry, guys, if i got you a little bit confused.

Comment: Can you please post an example of what you have tried so far ? What is the error ? How you wanted it to behave ?

Comment: Do you absolutely want to use regex here? The split method looks like a better option

Comment: @ArunKumar I have left an example on regex101's page. But i can show you. Example: **thirdlevel.domain.com**, **3rd-level.my-domain.com**, **fourth.level.domain**.com. This last domain is what i don't want to extract.

Comment: @Sam Yeah, i want to use only regex to solve this problem. But if it's okay to you, you can show me how can i handle this using split. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to extract only the 3rd level domain (e.g. *thirdlevel* from *thirdlevel.domain.com*) or do you want to validate *whether* a domain contains a third level (aka subdomain)?

Comment: This might help. https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: @mrzo I want to extract whole _thirdlevel.domain.com_ but if it's have another subdomain like _thisisnot.thirdlevel.domain.com_ i don't want to extract that domain at all. I hope i did make it clear. Thanks :)

Comment: I understand the entire "not using third party modules" thing but split seems like the right option here. @Slayer598

Comment: you could try `(?:(?<=: )|(?<=://)|^)((?:[\w-]+\.){2}\w+\.?(?:/.*)?)$`

Answer (score 0):

> *Example: thirdlevel.domain.com, 3rd-level.my-domain.com,
>   fourth.level.domain.com. This last domain is what i don't want to
>   extract.*

You can use [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/), i.e.:

```
import tldextract as tlde
doms = ['3rd-level.my-domain.com', "fourth.level.domain.com"]
good_third = [x.split(".")[0] for x in doms if not "." in tlde.extract(x).subdomain]
# ['3rd-level']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier when using url-parsing modules like tldextract:

```
from tldextract import extract

urls = [
    "thirdlevel.domain.com", 
    "ftp://thirdlevel.domain.com/index.php", 
    "3rdlevel.domain.com", "3rd-level.domain-my.COM.",
    "fourth.level.domain.com", "domain.com"
]
for url in urls:
    results = extract(url)
    subdomain = results.subdomain
    if subdomain:
        # Just get the 3rd level domain:
        third_level_domain = subdomain.split('.')[-1]
        print(third_level_domain)
```

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help, but how can i solve this problem changing my regular expression? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(?<!\.)\b[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+\.\w+\b(?!\.)
```

demo:

https://regex101.com/r/1e8jC7/1

Answer (score -1):

Using split:

```
s.split('//')[1].split('/')[0].split('.')[-3]
```

Comment: This will fail on all urls in the example that do not contain any slashes.

Comment: I am confused as well but they are in Slayer598's example link: https://regex101.com/r/uO5lJ0/15

Comment: You can't possibly have a solution based on patterns if there is no pattern so I assumed the URLs would follow basic RFC. In case you are the one who downvoted, may I ask you to re-consider?

Comment: You could change it to `s.split('//')[-1].split('/')[0].split('.')[-3]`(the first split index from 1 to -1) to match urls without slashes

Comment: But then again, "https://google.com" without www will throw an error. At some point, you have to assume that we are dealing with somewhat valid input, otherwise it becomes impossible to solve. So where do you draw the line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209277/discussion-between-mrzo-and-sam).